# CSS and frameset?

Tags: html, css, frames, frameset

I have an .html document of XHTML 1.0 Frameset doctype and I'm using the following code:

```
  <frameset rows="20%, 80%" border="1">
   ...
  </frameset>
```

When putting the above .html code in W3C Validator I get the following error:

**there is no attribute "border" in frameset**.

What can I do, in order to prevent this error? I tried creating a css file with:

```
frameset {
   border: 1px;
}
```

but didn't seem to work.

Please don't comment/answer telling me how bad frames are (I know by myself).

Comment: But your code works?? or not ??

Comment: Yes it does work just fine, having borders of width 1px when using border="1" attribute in frameset

Comment: if it does work, then it's much easier not to pay attention to validator. :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, use this instead:

```
<frameset ...>
   <frame frameborder="xx"/>
</frameset>
```

[see http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-10259.html ]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although with frameborder it's valid XHTML 1.0 Frameset code ... frameborder="1" doesn't seem to work, the borderwidth is much more than 1px.

Answer (score 0):

What if you gave your frameset a class and then put the class in the stylesheet?